# Coffeescript forEach function undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I am trying to write a FizzBuzz program with CoffeeScript like this:

```
array = [1..100]

console.log(array.forEach(
  (value)->
   if value%3 is 0 and value%5 is 0
    return "fizzbuz"
   if value%3 is 0
    return "fizz"
   if value%5 is 0
    return "buzz"
   value
   ))
```

And it keeps returning `undefined`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

The [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method doesn't return a resulting array. It executes a function once for each array element, and it doesn't return anything. If you want to return a resulting array, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
console.log(array.map(
  (value)->
    if value%3 is 0 and value%5 is 0
      return "fizzbuzz"
    if value%3 is 0
      return "fizz"
    if value%5 is 0
      return "buzz"
    value
  ))
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/YA86K/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using CoffeeScript, simple [`for` loops are expressions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) that result in arrays so you could say:

```
console.log(for value in array
    if value % 3 is 0 and value % 5 is 0
        "fizzbuz"
    else if value % 3 is 0
        "fizz"
    else if value % 5 is 0
        "buzz"
    else
        value
)
```

or if you really wanted to use a function, use `do` to create an SIF:

```
console.log(for value in array
    do (value) ->
        return 'fizzbuz' if value % 3 is 0 and value % 5 is 0
        return 'fizz'    if value % 3 is 0
        return 'buzz'    if value % 5 is 0
        return value
)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ENLfx/